# How to configure Wi-Fi on Debian 9 stretch with network card Intel Corporation Wireless 8260?

Tags: debian, wifi

I installed Debian 9 stretch testing version. And I did the below:

```
# apt-get update
# apt-get install network-manager-gnome
# apt-get install firmware-iwlwifi
```

My network card is Intel Corporation Wireless 8260

```
# lspci | grep Wireless
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)
```

So I come to [Linux Support for Intel wireless adapter](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005511.html) to download the Wi-Fi driver.

```
Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260       4.1     iwlwifi-8000-ucode-25.30.13.0.tgz
```

And I put the Wi-Fi driver under `/lib/firmware`.

But when I click Wi-Fi in the notification area, "Select network", the Wi-Fi networks pops up, "No network" message is displayed. It seems that it cannot detect the Wi-Fi.

Does anybody know the reason?

Comment: Reloading the driver `modprobe -r iwlwifi ; modprobe iwlwifi` doesn't help?

Comment: Thanks GAD3R! # modprobe -r iwlwifi; modprobe: FATAL: Module iwlwifi is in use; # modprobe iwlwifi; no return message. But when I open "Select Networks", the wifi driver cannot detect the wifi SSID.

Comment: To unload/reload iwlwifi, first `modprobe -r iwlmvm || modprobe -r iwldvm`. Or use `lsmod|grep iwlwifi`, it will tell you which one of the two sub-modules is loaded & using iwlwifi, so you can unload it first.

Comment: Thanks sourcejedi. I had wifi icon on my top right corner of desktop. But when I clicking Select Network, it seems that the network card cannot find the surrounding wifi SSID.

Answer (score 3):

To install the wifi for the Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 , download the driver from [here](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi), extract it then copy it to your `/lib/firmware`:

```
wget https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/_media/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi-8000-ucode-16.242414.0.tgz
tar xvf iwlwifi-8000-ucode-16.242414.0.tgz
cd iwlwifi-8000-ucode-16.242414.0
cp iwlwifi-8000-ucode* /lib/firmware
modprobe iwlwifi
```

Comment: Thanks GAD3R,  I tried, but still cannot figure out. The wifi networks still cannot find the surrounding wifi SSID. I don't know why.  Does it related to /etc/network/interfaces? I have the following interfaces: auto lo iface lo inet loopback. I also used iwconfig, it is as below: wlp4s0 IEEE 802.11 ESSID:off/any Mode: Managed Access Point: Not-Associated Tx-Power=0 dBm Retry short limit: 7 RTS thr: off Fragment thr: off Encryption key: off Power Management: on Enp0s31f6 no wireless extensions. lo no wireless extensions.

Comment: GAD3R, it seems that I did not configure IP address manually. When I use "ip address show", it displays the following information: 3: wlp4s0: <BROADCAST, MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000 link/ether 1a:15:e3:83:e7:61 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Comment: Run `ip link set wlp4s0 up` then try to scan for the AP through `iw dev wlp4s0 scan`

Comment: GAD3R, I ran ip link set wlp4s0, it says RTNETLINK answers: Input/output error